# Complexity, Autometa can anyone please explain this?

Tags: complexity-theory

Let L1 ⊆ {0, 1}∗ and L2 ⊆ {0, 1}∗ be RE (recursively enumer-
able) languages such that L1 ∪ L2 = {0, 1}∗ and L1 ∩ L2 6= ∅. Prove that L1
is algorithmically reducible to L1 ∩ L2, that is, there is an algorithm which,
for every w ∈ {0, 1}∗, constructs a suitable v ∈ {0, 1}∗ such that w ∈ L1 if
and only if v ∈ L1 ∩ L2.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask this question on https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead, it might be more suitable there.

Comment: I dont think this is complexity theory, looks more like formal languages to me